# Bitcoin core v0.20.1 mining, am i doing it right? using "generatetoaddress"

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory

I am using the official bitcoin core client downloaded from bitcoin.org

i have googled this question multiple times finding only virus warning files or forums with links to outdated information and i cant find a concrete answer for the latest version 0.20.1 for my question (ill make it simple) "which command do i type into bitcoin core console to mine?"

How can i "get" a new block for a "reward" of the current reward btc as a "miner"?

i have tried "nicehash" for 2 hours but that netted me like $0.03 and a very hot machine haha

i know the chances are very very low for me to solo mine (for example bitcoin core uses only CPU which is very inefficient apparently), i dont care, i want to do it anyway, i know there are other mining software out there but i want to use bitcoin core, to get it mining and working properly

i have tried

```
getmininginfo
```

which gave me back output which i mostly understand (but no errors)

then i tried:

```
getblocktemplate "{\"rules\":[\"segwit\"]}"
```

which spewed out a lot of information which i do not fully understand yet... (but no errors)

currently i am trying :

```
generatetoaddress 1 "*** address removed***" (999999999)
```

which takes about 17 minutes to complete and i get a return of in the console:

What is the following output? is it an error?

```
11:**:**
￼
[
]
```

Question: is this the right method:

```
generatetoaddress 1 "*** address removed***" (999999999)
```

above to mine the current 6.25btc reward with bitcoin core?

i know the odds are slim but is this the right command?

if so, this command currently takes 17 mins, should i try less iterations (default or 1 or other low number?) with a higher nblock value?

of note: using iterations less than 999999999 results in the command processing quickly (1 second not 17 minutes)

if this is wrong command then why however in the debug file do i find this after using the command?:

```
2021-01-**T11:**:**Z CreateNewBlock(): block weight: ******** txs: **** fees: ********* sigops *****
```

Question: what does this above output tell me? please note i have put stars (*) to hide possibly sensitive info

Question: How can i speed up the response of 17 minutes for my command:

> generatetoaddress 1 "address" (999999999)

? in task manager the bitcoin core program is using about 15% cpu and about 800mb ram

can i increase its resources for a faster response in the console for my command which currently takes 17 minutes to compute?

Comment: You are not trying to do something sensible. Your question has excluded all the good answers already. It's really a lot like "How can I use a jackhammer to put in a screw? I don't want to use a screwdriver."

Comment: Do you have a constructive answer? i dont understand what you mean by "your question has excluded all the good answers already." please tell me how this comment helps .

Comment: You insist on using one particular tool and you insist on doing one particular job, but the tool you have picked is entirely unsuitable for the job you have picked. How can anyone give you a constructive answer? What's a constructive answer to "how do I put in a screw with a jackhammer?" except "Don't use that tool or use that tool to do something else".

Comment: again your comments/replies have added nothing to my initial question discussion.

Comment: As I said, they're not going to because you are asking a question that does not have a constructive answer beyond "don't do that, do something else". We could point you to other things to do, but you've asked us not to. You've completely tied our hands.

Comment: I have a constructive answer from another user now, your comments are not needed or helpful, also, who is 'we'? i haven't tied your [(our) who else are you with?] hands, how have i done that? you just wont/cant answer my question and instead have made comments which i have now flagged...

Comment: It is weird to me that you keep purporting to reply to what I'm saying without actually replying to what I'm saying. Please read what I'm actually saying and respond to the things I've actually said. Imagine a question like, "I want to put in a screw with a jackhammer. I only want to use a jackhammer. And only want to put in a screw." What would a constructive answer to that question look like? Do you see how that question ties the answerer's hands by ruling out all possible constructive answers? Your question is like that. Really.

Comment: You can change the question to one that has constructive answers by removing some restrictions. But otherwise, every answer you get will be one that you don't like and won't accept because it won't actually answer your question because you've already excluded every possible constructive answer by the form of your question.

Comment: i have an answer which i like already, your comments are no longer needed in this discussion , send me a pm if you want to continue

Comment: I think what @DavidSchwartz was attempting to point out, is that this question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232061). Instead of asking about the underlying problem you're trying to solve, you asked about your specific attempted solution. From what I can tell, your underlying question is "How can I mine with my home computer?". Michael recognized that and posted a "frame challenge": he answered the underlying question sidestepping most of your actual questions which David was pointing out didn't have good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin Core on its own does not support mining. You need to run additional mining software with Bitcoin Core.

`generatetoaddress` can only be used on regtest which is for local testing. Any Bitcoin generated to this address are not worth anything.

> i have tried "nicehash" for 2 hours but that netted me like $0.03 and a very hot machine haha

This sounds about right unfortunately. The total network hash rate according to [blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/charts/hash-rate) is over 100 million terahashes per second. We are long past the point where CPU solo mining can successfully mine a block. You will be waiting for many years before you do. The best you can hope for is to sign up to a mining pool and generate the odd cent.

Comment: how certain are you bitcoin core does not support mining on its own? or is that just a general consensus which you have adopted? for example does it explicitly state anywhere on bitcoin.org that mining with their bitcoin core is no longer possible?

Comment: 100 percent certain. Bitcoin Core can work with additional mining software but without that additional mining software there is nothing you can do exclusively with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: i look forward other users input and/or to a link from bitcoin.org to prove what your saying is correct: "there is nothing you can do exclusively with Bitcoin Core"

Comment: With regards to mining that's true. Bitcoin Core does **a lot** but it won't mine for you :)

Comment: You could in 2016 https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/how-to-activate-the-mining-process-in-the-standard-bitcoin-client

Comment: i can see from https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/89916/113472 which is a discussion from a long time ago that bitcoin core no longer supports mining, but he doesnt back it up with any bitcoin.org proof?

Comment: bitcoin.org isn't an authoritative resource. The codebase of Bitcoin Core is the authoritative resource.

Comment: thank you for your comment and link, unfortunately the setgenerate command is no longer supported! :) yet i still wonder if its possible ...

Comment: Removed in version 0.13 https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.13.0#removal-of-internal-miner

Comment: thankyou i now can see that the internal miner has been removed , big shame !

Comment: @RLRTech2021: It was just completely hopeless to use regular computers after 2013: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/41277/5406